# Detecting if an answering service picks up

Tags: twilio

In our Twilio application a number is dialed, the call is recorded, and it's url is emailed to an administrator. An issue occurs when nobody is there to answer the call and the clients call answering service picks up and deals with the caller (perhaps forwarding them to another number). Can we detect when the answering service picks up to handle the call and terminate the recording/hangup? Is there an event raised? I understand we can detect when an answering machine picks up (beeps) but is the above possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Evangelist here.

We do have [answering machine detection](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#handling-outcomes-answering-machines), but please be aware that answering machine detection by any service is way more art than science.

To use Twilios answering machine detection, you include the [ifMachine parameter](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional) in your TwiML.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It seems the [`<dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) doesn't say anything about ifMachine. It is only described in Rest API section. Should we assume if we add `ifMachine="Continue/Hangup"`it will work?

Answer (score 1):

Also note than in the UK there are regulations on answerphone detection from OFCOM in regards to silent calls.

There can be big fines for breaching this, TalkTalk were fined £750,000 this year.

Read more here: https://www.ofcom.org.uk/about-ofcom/latest/media/media-releases/2011/ofcom-warns-industry-as-new-silent-calls-rules-come-into-force